Where can I see a Pay to Anchor output in the wild?
I'm reading about the new features of the Bitcoin Core 28 release and would like to see one of those PayToAnchor outputs on either mainnet, testnet, or signet. Can anyone provide me with a link to one?

Here are some links for them on mempool.space:

Mainnet
Signet/Testnet

